# add id column on INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to have a AI ID column added when I do a:

```
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM(...
```

statement.

I am doing it from a query with multiple joins and need to have a ID generated for every row that gets inserted into a new table that is being created from the query.

I am using SSMS 2012

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: Please make it clear

Comment: SSMS 2012...my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `SQL SERVER` we have [**`IDENTITY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189838.aspx) function

> Is used only in a SELECT statement with an INTO table clause to insert
>   an identity column into a new table. Although similar, the IDENTITY
>   function is not the IDENTITY property that is used with CREATE TABLE
>   and ALTER TABLE.

Try something like this

```
SELECT identity(int,1,1) as ID_Num,* 
INTO newTable 
FROM(...
```